# Javascript doesn't work in my localhost using Google App ENgine

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine

Im stuck since a week and I allready looked in a million spanish and english forums...

The thing is that Javascript does not work on my localhost when I launch my website from Google App Engine.

If I copy/paste all the html, css and .js files and then I launch in the browser from Notepad++ works perfectly, but for any reason does not work on GAE, and I don´t know why.

The app.yaml works because if I write in the browser:

`http://localhost:8080/js/script.js` , then appear the javascript code.

Here is all my code:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ingles").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

My app.yaml:

```
application: juanmamorenoportfolio
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /images
  static_dir: static_files/images

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: .*
  upload: templates/index.html
  static_files: templates/index.html

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

and my main.py (I suspect the problem should be here):

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: Is your `jquery` file referenced correctly? Is there an element on the page with and an `Id` of `ingles`?

Comment: Are there errors reported in the browser console?

Comment: No errors in the browser console. http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.js displays the js code too and yes, there is an <a> element called "ingles"

Comment: Everything looks fine, that is why I suspect its something with my main.py file, the app.yaml or other unexpected issue

Answer (score 0):

Javascript works perfectly on SDK and production.

1. app.yaml is wrong - write correct path to jquery.js.
2. Put file where is required or you point before.
3. Check if you regex in urls specification since it is not simple strings.
4. Maybe `upload:` is required in `- url:`.
5. Try `http://localhost:8080/js/script.js` to check if code is shown.
6. Check page if HTML is ok.
7. Check if $ is defined in i.e. Chrome Console.
8. Vote for my answer.

Read documentation [Static file handlers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers).

Comment: the path to jquery.js works, if i run localhost:8080/js/jquery.js the browser display the jquery code (as text). How to do the "upload:" thing? Why this is important? The official documentation is not very clear with this issue

Comment: upload is some regex for file it not required but if it required you need specify path from app.yaml /js/jquery\.js (adjust it to your project).

Comment: If you see source code the problem is not serving - it is HTML or usage - see in Chrome Network activity if it load on page and with what headers for content-type. By default gae serving js without problem. I looks that is your mistake or some too strong antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has to do with the `upload:` thing:  [Static file pattern handlers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers)

Comment: upload is not need for localhost but for upload it is need